# Trace http packets using Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, xmpp, trace, packet

I've developed a website where I am using XMPP with Strophe.JS

There's one error that I'm trying to locate which is 404 INVALID SID. I can only find it now using the Network console under inspect element in the browser.

So, I'm trying to find a solution on how to detect it automatically in Javascript. I only need to trace the http packets to be able to solve it.

Any recommendation will be great! Thanks!

Comment: but when do you get the error? on which call?ù

Comment: Sometimes, after many page refresh, when I try to attach the session, I get a 404 invalid SID. So I want to be able to detect it so that I can re-connect to my XMPP server.